opening a file that exists, EEXIST error bug
In my Next.js application (v14.2.2) I want to read MDX files and show them as blogpost on my website. For this I am using the package next-mdx-remote. Locally it works perfectly. However in production on a virtual host I get the error that a file already exists. This leads to an error 500.
This is the exact error in the stderr.log file:
⨯ Error: open EEXIST
    at new Socket (node:net:428:13)
    at process.getStdin [as stdin] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:224:17)
    at get (<anonymous>)
    at getOwn (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:206:5)
    at BuiltinModule.syncExports (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:378:31)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:358:17)
    at BuiltinModule.getESMFacade (node:internal/bootstrap/realm:363:17)
    at ModuleLoader.builtinStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:468:17)
    at callTranslator (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:279:14)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:285:30) {
  errno: -17,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  syscall: 'open'
}

This is my code in Next.js:
async function getPostByName(fileID: string): Promise<BlogPost | undefined> {


    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, `${fileID}.mdx`);
    const rawMDX  = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8');

    const { frontmatter, content } = await compileMDX<{
        title: string, summary: string, date_created: string, date_updated: string, tags: string[], path: string }>({
        source: rawMDX as MDXRemoteProps['source'],
        components: { Video, CustomImage, CustomLink },
        options: {
            parseFrontmatter: true,
            mdxOptions: {
                format: 'mdx',
            },
        }
    });

    return { meta: { id: fileID, title: frontmatter.title, summary: frontmatter.summary, date_created: frontmatter.date_created, date_updated: frontmatter.date_updated, tags: frontmatter.tags, path: frontmatter.path }, content }
}


export default async function BlogPage() {


    const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory);
    const ids = fileNames.map((fileName) => {
        return fileName.replace(/\.mdx$/, '');
    });

    const posts: Meta[] = [];

    for (const id of ids) {
        const post = await getPostByName(id);
        if (post) {
                const {meta} = post;
                posts.push(meta);
            }

    }
    posts.sort((a, b) => (a.date_created < b.date_created ? 1 : -1));


    // const posts = await getPostsMeta();

    if (!posts) return <span>Something went wrong</span>

    return (
        <BlogPageClient posts={posts}/>
    )
}

Do you know what could be the cause?
